# Handle errors with parallel async requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, vue.js, request

I have 6 async requests. If one of them gives an error, returns 404, other requests doesn't work too. I use `async.parallel` to make these requests. I'm trying to make working other requests when one of them fails. But I couldn't make it.

Here is my code:

```
    async.parallel({
      request1: async (callback) => {
        const [err, result] = await to(this.$store.dispatch('myAction1', {
          id: this.$route.params.id,
        }));
        callback(err, result);
      },
      request2: async (callback) => {
        const [err, result] = await to(this.$store.dispatch('myAction2', {
          params: {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            page: this.page,
            size: this.size,
          },
        }));
        callback(err, result);
      },
      request3: async (callback) => {
        const [err, result] = await to(this.$store.dispatch('myAction3', {
          data: {
            filters: this.inputs.filters,
            projections: this.inputs.projections,
            showTotalCount: this.inputs.showTotalCount,
          },
          params: {
            page: this.page,
            size: this.size,
          },
        }));
        callback(err, result);
      },
      request4: async (callback) => {
        const [err, result] = await to(this.$store.dispatch('myAction4'));
        callback(err, result);
      },
      request5: async (callback) => {
        const [err, result] = await to(this.$store.dispatch('myAction5', {
          id: this.$route.params.id,
        }));
        callback(err, result);
      },
      request6: async (callback) => {
        const [err, result] = await to(this.$store.dispatch('myAction6', {
          params: {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
          },
        }));
        callback(err, result);
      },
    }, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        // Show error message when one of them fails
      }
      // doing something when all requests success and hide the page loader.
      this.hidePageLoader();
    });
```

This code always shows page loader if one these requests returns 404, I want to pass failed request as `null` to my `results` object or return other results without having failed request in `results` object. How can I make it properly

Answer (score 0):

For the rest of the tasks to continue processing even if any of the other fails, you need to push the tasks to an array where each task is wrapped in `async.reflect` and set the array of tasks as first argument to `async.parallel`.

For example:

```
async.parallel([
 async.reflect((callback) => {
   return callback(null, "one");
 }),
 async.reflect((callback) => {
   return callback("error");
 }),
 // another tasks
], function(error, results) {
  if(error)
    return cb(error)

  // results[0].value ->> "one"
  // results[1].error ->> "error"

  return cb(results)
})
```

Source: [Async Documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#reflect) `utils` *>>* `reflect`